# Div on top of jquery cycle plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I am using the jquery cycle plugin and I want to add a section over the slides show where people can log in.  This an example how I would like it to look.

[mycampus.astate.edu](http://mycampus.astate.edu)

I understand how the cycle plugin works, I just can't figure out how to put things on top of it. I would really appreciate any assistance provided.

Thanks!

Comment: Just set a higher z-index in the CSS for your page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/z-index

Comment: @user2258356 In general you should mark the correct answer by clicking the checkmark next to the one that helps you. This ensures that future users are also helped and is how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this using a few of the options for the slideshow:

First, let's add the login box, in my example it has id `login` and we will also tell the plugin to select the slides based on the selector '> div.cycle-slide' so that the login div isn't considered a slide.    Lastly, we just need to make sure and set the z-index of the login box to be above the slides.

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/87FUR/3/

HTML:

```
 <div class="cycle-slideshow item" data-cycle-timeout="3000" data-cycle-speed="2000" data-cycle-slides="> div.cycle-slide" data-cycle-fx="fade">
    <div id="login">Your Login here</div>
    <div class="cycle-slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/550x550/" />

    </div>
    <div class="cycle-slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/550x550/ff0000" /> 

    </div>
    <div class="cycle-slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/550x550/" />

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.cycle-slideshow {
    width: 550px;
    height: 550px;
}
#login {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:blue;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity: .5;
}
img {
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
}
```